# Binding DataGrid Column DataTemplate to Attached Property

Tags: wpf, datatemplate, datagridcolumn, datagridcolumnheader

I am trying to customize a *DataGridColumnHeader* to show multiple text fields instead of
showing only the header text provided by *DataGridColumn.Header* property.
If i didn't miss something, i just have to create a *DataTemplate* and bind to the properties
of the parent object. This works fine for the *DataGridColumn.Header* property but
binding to attached property fails.

For the sake of completeness, implementation of the attached property:

```
public static class CustomHeader
{
    public static string GetUnit(DependencyObject obj) { return (string)obj.GetValue(UnitProperty); }
    public static void SetUnit(DependencyObject obj, string value) { obj.SetValue(UnitProperty, value); }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty UnitProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "Unit", typeof(string), typeof(CustomHeader), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

Usage in the Xaml-Markup:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="tObjectDataGrid" Margin="10,50,10,10" 
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True"  
                  ItemsSource="{Binding ObjectList}"  
                  RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected" >
  <DataGrid.Resources>  
    <DataTemplate x:Key="CustomHeaderTemplate">  
      <StackPanel>  
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />  
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=(cust:CustomHeader.Unit)}" /> <-- attached binding doesn't work :( 
      </StackPanel>  
    </DataTemplate>  
  </DataGrid.Resources>  

  <DataGrid.Columns>  
    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="SpeedColumn"
                        Width="1*"
                        Binding="{Binding Speed}"
                        Header="Speed"
                        HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource CustomHeaderTemplate}"
                        cust:CustomHeader.Unit="[m/s]" />  
  </DataGrid.Columns>  
</DataGrid>
```

I really appreciate any comment or weblink that clarifies what i am missing here.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where have you set this `attached property`?

Comment: It is set in DataGridTextColumn's last line ... cust:CustomHeader.Unit="[m/s]". The class 'CustomHeader' is situated in the same assembly (in a testproject) and in the same namespace as the rest of the testproject. "cust" is xmlns:cust="clr-namespace:DependencyTest" (to be complete) ... does this setup maybe introduce unexpected sideeffects?

Comment: Behaviour is completely fine since you set attached property on `DataGridTextColumn` and `HeaderTemplate` not lies in the `Visual Tree` of your column. Hence not inheriting the attached property. If you set the default value for your property to say `TestString`, that value will be shown in header.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use multi value converter ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter.aspx)).

XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="tObjectDataGrid" Margin="10,50,10,10" 
          AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True"  
          ItemsSource="{Binding ObjectList}"  
          RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected" >
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <cust:UnitConverter x:Key="unitCon" />
        <DataTemplate x:Key="CustomHeaderTemplate">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                <TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock.Text>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource unitCon}">
                            <Binding Path="Columns" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGrid}" />
                            <Binding Path="." />
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </TextBlock.Text>
                </TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGrid.Resources>

    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="SpeedColumn"
                Width="1*"
                Binding="{Binding Speed}"
                Header="Speed"
                HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource CustomHeaderTemplate}"
                cust:CustomHeader.Unit="[m/s]" />

        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="SpeedColumn2"
                Width="1*"
                Binding="{Binding Speed2}"
                Header="Speed2"
                HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource CustomHeaderTemplate}"
                cust:CustomHeader.Unit="[km/h]" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Code-behind:

```
public class UnitConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string result = null;

        ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn> columns = values[0] as ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn>;
        string headerName = values[1].ToString();

        var coll = columns.Where(x => x.Header.ToString() == headerName).FirstOrDefault();

        if (coll != null)
            result = CustomHeader.GetUnit(coll);

        return result;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I think that better solution will be create new class e.g `HeaderData` and after that you can create instance of it in xaml and binding to this class.

Example:

Class to hold header data:

```
class HeaderData
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Unit { get; set; }
}
```

XAML code:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="tObjectDataGrid" Margin="10,50,10,10" 
          AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True"  
          ItemsSource="{Binding ObjectList}"  
          RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected" >
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="CustomHeaderTemplate">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Unit}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="SpeedColumn"
                        Width="1*"
                        Binding="{Binding Speed}"                                
                        HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource CustomHeaderTemplate}">             
            <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                <cust:HeaderData Name="Speed" Unit="[m/s]" />
            </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="SpeedColumn2"
                        Width="1*"
                        Binding="{Binding Speed2}"                                
                        HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource CustomHeaderTemplate}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                <cust:HeaderData Name="Speed2" Unit="[km/h]" />
            </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Thank you. The second approach looks very nice from the easyness viewpoint. So i marked that as answer.
I am just wondering because i thought attached properties should solve exactly such a point i encountered.
When i want to bind the two textvalues in cust:HeaderData i guess i have to implement the properties as dependencyproperties? Or do i have to derive from dependencyobject?

Comment: No, you can create simple properties and you don't have to derive from DependencyObject. In my answer I showed you example class.

Comment: I'm trying to use this solution but with two-way binding with `TextBox`. So, instead of having hard-coded value `Unit="[km/h]"`, I would like to have something like `Unit="{Binding Unit, Mode=TwoWay}"`.
I tried with attached property and with separate class, but I can't get the value to propagate back to my view-model. In attached property example, the problem is in `ConvertBack` as I don't have information how to call `SetUnit(obj, value)`. In `HeaderData` case, I get the value to the `HeaderData.Unit` property, but not all the way back to my view-model. I'm completely stuck now.

Answer (score 1):

At first glance, your code is normal, should work. But when your dependency property is set to `DataGridTextColumn`, `SetUnit` not called and the variable `Unit` value `NULL`. I tried to assign a value of attached dependency property in `Window` (since it attached, you can set its value anywhere) in this case must work:

```
<Window x:Class="DataGridAttachedHelp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataGridAttachedHelp"
    local:CustomHeader.Unit="[m/s]"
    Name="MyWindow"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">

<Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="tObjectDataGrid" Margin="10,50,10,10" 
              AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True"                    
              RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected" >

        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="CustomHeaderTemplate">
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=(local:CustomHeader.Unit), ElementName=MyWindow}" />
                </StackPanel>  
            </DataTemplate>  
        </DataGrid.Resources>  

        <DataGrid.Columns>  
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="SpeedColumn" Width="1*" Binding="{Binding Speed}" Header="Speed"
                    HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource CustomHeaderTemplate}" />  
        </DataGrid.Columns>  
    </DataGrid>      
</Grid>
</Window>
```

In your case the property did not work, because it is necessary to indicate the source of the properties, for example: `ElementName`, `Source`. Therefore, simply add the name of `DataGridTextColumn` in parameter `ElementName`:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=(local:CustomHeader.Unit), ElementName=SpeedColumn}" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This solves it for one DataColumn. I also tried to bind using RelativeSource but failed to get the proper ancestor in my example. My intention is, to easily apply some more information on the header using a DynamicResource string, image and so on for each column. So directly managing it over an attached property at window/usercontrol-level is not fully matching my needs .